# How to create a new window on the current directory in tmux?

Tags: tmux, terminal-multiplexer

Is is possible to open a `new-window` with its working directory set to the one I am currently in. I am using *zsh*, if it matters.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Starting in *tmux* 1.9 the `default-path` option was removed, so you need to use the `-c` option with `new-window`, and `split-window` (e.g. by rebinding the `c`, `"`, and `%` bindings to include
`-c '#{pane_current_path}'`). See some of the other answers to this question for details.

---

A relevant feature landed in the *tmux* SVN trunk in early February 2012. In *tmux* builds that include this code, *tmux* key bindings that invoke `new-window` will create new a window with the same current working directory as the current pane’s active processes (as long as the `default-path` session option is empty; it is by default). The same is true for the pane created by the `split-window` command when it is invoked via a binding.

This uses special platform-specific code, so only certain OSes are supported at this time: Darwin (OS X), FreeBSD, Linux, OpenBSD, and Solaris.

This should be available in the next release of *tmux* (1.7?).

---

With *tmux* 1.4, I usually just use

```
tmux neww
```

in a shell that already has the desired current working directory.

If, however, I anticipate needing to create many windows with the same current working directory (or I want to be able to start them with the usual <prefix>`c` key binding), then I set the `default-path` session option via

```
tmux set-option default-path "$PWD"
```

in a shell that already has the desired current working directory (though you could obviously do it from any directory and just specify the value instead).

If `default-path` is set to a non-empty value, its value will be used instead of “inheriting” the current working directory from command-line invocations of `tmux neww`.

The [*tmux* FAQ](https://github.com/ddollar/tmux/blob/d48eb68e5/FAQ#L330) has an entry titled “How can I open a new window in the same directory as the current window?” that describes another approach; it is a bit convoluted though.

Comment: Is there a way I can map `<prefix>c` to read the working directory of the underlying shell instance (if any) and set the `default-path` prior to executing `new-window`. Or is that too much to ask of *tmux* :)

Comment: On another note, is it even possible to read the underlying shell's working directory? I'd kill to have it displayed in my status bar.

Comment: There is no portable way to extract the cwd of another process (though it is possible on some platforms (e.g. `/proc/PID/cwd` on Linux)). There is a possible partial solution in [an entry](http://tmux.cvs.sf.net/viewvc/tmux/tmux/FAQ?r1=1.39&r2=1.40) of the *tmux* FAQ (it has the shell record its cwd when it prints a prompt, then binds a key that starts a new shell in the recorded directory).

Comment: ok, this is a bit out of scope for my knowledge and doesn't feel very reliable. Something tells me I may be better off without all this.. thanks anyway.

Comment: I was hoping this would be easier to add. I have been enjoying automatically switching to the current directory in iTerm2 and would love to find the same convenience in Tmux.

Comment: @Chris: Is it possible to bind a key combination to `tmux neww` in `.tmux.conf` and is it possible to do something similar with new panes or sessions, as well as windows?

Comment: @paradroid:
Anything done via a binding will (by default) use the cwd of the *tmux* server or the value of the `default-path` session option (if that is set). 
The [tmux FAQ](http://tmux.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tmux/trunk/FAQ) has an entry that describes a way to bind a key that starts a new window with the cwd of the shell running in the current window (“How can I open a new window in the same directory as the current window?”), but the method is quite convoluted.
The same could probably be done for `split-window` and `new-session` (instead of `neww`).

Comment: This post makes the situation look dire but the fact is that recent versions of tmux handle this perfectly, as indicated in the answer below.

Comment: That tmux FAQ URL no longer works, and the new one (https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ) doesn't have that named *How can I open a new window in the same directory as the current window?*. Here's a mirror of the old one: https://github.com/ddollar/tmux/blob/d48eb68e5/FAQ#L330

Comment: I bind 'C' to open another window in current dir using `pane_current_path` -> `bind C new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68838778/117714

Answer (score 417):

The current (1.9a) Tmux man page lists an optional `-c start-directory` parameter for some commands, including `new-window` and `split-window`.
It also contains the format variable `pane_current_path`, which refers to the
`Current path if available`.

By combining these, we can open a new window with the current working directory using
`new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"`
The quotation are needed in case the current path contains spaces.

If you want to split the current pane vertically, use
`split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"`
or, for a horizontal split
`split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"`

To make the key bindings open new splits and windows with the current working directory by default, add the following to your `.tmux.conf`. The `"` with surrounding quotes is to tell Tmux it shouldn't start a string but rather bind the <kbd>"</kbd> key.

```
bind '"' split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

Comment: Does this not work on tmux 1.9? I can't get it to do the expected thing.

Comment: It should: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/1.9/CHANGES#L12
I'd suggest using a more recent version, though

Comment: bind-key -r Enter new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}", works for tmux 2.1

Comment: Works in tmux 2.3 on OSX. Don't forget to stop / kill all existing sessions to see these bindings applied.

Comment: @jmgarnier or re-source the profile: `prefix`-`:`, then type `source ~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: @jmgarnier or just `tmux source-file .tmux.conf`.

Comment: Worked like a  charm in June 2014. Still works on tmux 2.5 (tested on FreeBSD) but I fear it doesn't work anymore on tmux 2.5 (tested on Arch). I wonder if this is not linked to the way systemd opens a session.

Comment: @Dereckson It works for me with tmux 2.9_a-4 on Arch Linux.

Comment: I turned this into a TPM plugin if anyone finds that to be more convenient: https://github.com/openjck/tmux-keep-current-directory

Comment: Using tmux 2.7 and this works perfectly. Thank you! For what it's worth, I personally find these bindings to be easier to remember for vertical and horizontal pane splits: `bind / split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"` and `bind - split-window -v -c "#{pane_current_path}"`

Comment: I am not sure why, but `bind | split-window -h` opens new pane under current directory, while `bind | split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"` opens new pane under home directory.

Comment: That exactly I want. `tmux 3.1c`

Answer (score 68):

Use `new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"`.

You can add the following to your `~/.tmux.conf` to make it persistent (assumming [default keybindings](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#DEFAULT_KEY_BINDINGS)):

```
bind  c  new-window      -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind  %  split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind '"' split-window -v -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

The `default-path` setting was [removed](https://github.com/ThomasAdam/tmux/commit/4538c269d0b366a770a5a5ebfe0c5007569edbc1) from 1.9 (released on Feb 2014). In the change, the author recommended using either `-c "#{pane_current_path}"` or `-c "$PWD` in the `new-window` and `split-window` commands.

*Also answered in this [duplicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101949/5576).*

Answer (score 12):

With recent versions of tmux (v1.8, but maybe in v1.7 too):

```
tmux new-window -c "$PWD"
```

Comment: This appears to work with split-window as well, e.g. `tmux split-window -v -c "$PWD"`

Comment: `$PWD` doesn't appear to work for me in tmux 1.9a. I had to use `pane_current_path` as suggested above.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers does not work for me when I try put them as bindings (specifically `tmux split-window -c`). But I've made up my own solution that I've been using for more than a year that works for both new-window and splits:

`~/.bashrc`:

```
PS1="$PS1"'$([ -n "$TMUX" ] && tmux setenv TMUXPWD_$(tmux display -p "#D" | tr -d %) "$PWD")'
```

`~/.tmux.conf`:

```
unbind-key c
bind-key c run-shell 'tmux new-window "cd \"$(tmux show-environment $(echo "TMUXPWD_#D" | tr -d %) | sed -e "s/^.*=//")\"; exec $SHELL"'
bind-key C new-window

bind-key - run-shell 'tmux split-window -v "cd \"$(tmux show-environment $(echo "TMUXPWD_#D" | tr -d %) | sed -e "s/^.*=//")\"; exec $SHELL"'
bind-key | run-shell 'tmux split-window -h "cd \"$(tmux show-environment $(echo "TMUXPWD_#D" | tr -d %) | sed -e "s/^.*=//")\"; exec $SHELL"
```

Works, at least, with $(tmux -V) 1.8. See out-commented lines [here](https://github.com/erikw/dotfiles/blob/personal/.tmux.conf) for a version working for older tmuxes that don't have the show-environment command.

Answer (score 1):

tmux did that in version 1.8 but in 1.9 this feature was removed in favor of using `-c` flag.

This can be solved but re-binding `new-window` but in case you want to run something else it becomes too wordy: instead of typing `neww man tmux` you'll have to type `neww -c "#{pane_current_path}" man tmux` which you most probably don't want to do.

There's a mod of tmux (I'm the author) to add a proper scripting language to tmux to allow using aliases, binding multiple commands in 'mode', variables, loops, etc...
And also, it brings back the that behavior: new windows and panes are opened in the current directory.

It can be built from sources here: http://ershov.github.io/tmux/