# New Tmux Panes go to the same directory as the current pane; new tmux windows go to home directory?

Tags: tmux

Can anyone help me set up this configuration?

If I create a new pane, the new pane should start out in the same working directory as the pane I was just in. If I create a new window, the new window should start out in the home directory (or any other global default path).

Is this possible with tmux 1.8?

Answer (score 88):

Add `-c "#{pane_current_path}"` to the `new-window`/`split-window` commands.

Example configuration using the default key bindings:

```
bind  c  new-window      -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind  %  split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind '"' split-window -v -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

I found the `pane_current_path` trick [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1350614#p1350614). It's also documented in upstream [`CHANGES`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/5391342b08f746239e3d0e2f729410af10a54b78/CHANGES#L199).

Comment: For me, $PWD does not work, but #{pane_current_path} works.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question, because he asked whether it was possible to have new windows start in the home directory. Based on this answer and the ones considered duplicates, I thought placing `bind c new-window -c "$HOME"` would work, but new windows are still created in the `pane_current_path`

Comment: If you want to override `<prefix>"` you have to escape the double quote like this: `bind '"' split-window -v -c "#{pane_current_path}"`. Hopefully saves someone some time.

Comment: I should add that the characters c,|,- after "bind" represent the keys used to create new panes. By default these are c,%,".

Comment: Since this was the first tmux config I modified, just wanted to say that after you add this to config, run `tmux source ~/.tmux.conf`

Answer (score 9):

While @mmoya's answer works for tmux version 1.9 and beyond, the `-c` option for `new-window` is not present in earlier versions.  For earlier versions, this requires a bit of mucking with `default-path`.  Here is how I have it set up in my `.tmux.conf` file.

```
set -g default-path "~"
bind % set default-path "" \; split-window -h \; set -u default-path
bind '"' set default-path "" \; split-window -v \; set -u default-path
```

This makes the `new-window` command use the global `default-path`.  However, when splitting a window into panes, it makes a local `default-path` to override it.