# tmux new pane has home directory as default instead of previous directory

Tags: tmux

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> (create a new pane) while in a pane, which has the `PWD` `/tmp` for example, the new pane starts as my home folder `~`.

I looked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109255/72471 and it helped me with the same issue concerning windows.

However, I couldn't fix the `split-window` issue by inserting

```
bind " split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

into my `~/.tmux.conf`.

I am using tmux 1.9a and therefor don't want a rather messy solution for older versions stated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132377/72471) (it doesn't work in my case, anyway):

```
bind '"' set default-path "" \; split-window -v \; set -u default-path
```

How can I tell `tmux` to set the default directory as the current path of a pane, when creating a new pane?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try specifying `v` for vertical or `h` for horizontal

My `.tmux.conf` file has:

```
bind \ split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'  # Split panes horizontal
bind - split-window -v -c '#{pane_current_path}'  # Split panes vertically
```

(I use `\` and `-` as one-finger pane splitters.)

New panes open for me using my current directory, wherever I am.
It's certainly a key feature for me!

One other critical thing with tmux (this was the issue in this case) is that you have to apply changes with:

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Note that closing terminals, even logging off and restarting, will NOT apply tmux changes – you have to actually use that command (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> `:source-file ~/.tmux.conf`).

You can see my full `.tmux.conf` file at https://github.com/durrantm/setups.

Comment: You said "Note that closing terminals, even logging off and restarting will NOT apply tmux changes".

Of course if you only detached tmux it won't but killing and restarting the server will apply changes :).

Comment: Thanks so much! This was super helpful. However, I'm pretty sure restarting the computer applies tmux changes :)

Comment: Restarting the computer did not apply changes for me previously leading to confusion for me. ymmv

Comment: Note that the same thing can be done for `new-window`

Answer (score 31):

```
bind '%' split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'  # Split panes horizontal
bind '"' split-window -v -c '#{pane_current_path}'  # Split panes vertically
bind c new-window -c '#{pane_current_path}' # Create new window
```

Add last line to your `~/.tmux.conf` to maintain `$PWD` in new window as well.

Answer (score 7):

That's because,

```
bind " split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

should be

```
bind '"' split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone gets here by searching, this works fine with tmux 2.7 and should be ok with likely all versions

```
unbind '"'
bind '"' split-window -v -c '#{pane_current_path}'  # Split panes vertically

unbind %
bind % split-window -h -c '#{pane_current_path}'  # Split panes horizontal
```