# How to change default new window directory from within the tmux

Tags: linux, tmux, gnu-screen

I recently moved from [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) to [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/).
I find it quite similar but with bigger support (I switched due to [problem with escape-time in neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2035)- resolution was only for tmux).

Unfortunately in tmux I'm unable to find a similar command to this:

```
screen -X eval "chdir $(some_dir)"
```

The command above changed the default directory for new window/screen/pane from within the GNU screen so when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (similar to tmux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>)- new window opened in the `$(some_dir)` directory.

Is there a similar thing in tmux?

ANSWER:
I have used @Lqueryvg answer and combined it with @Vincent Nivoliers suggestion froma a comment and that gave me a new binding for a command `attach -c "#{pane_current_path}"` which sets my current directory as a default one.
Thanks.

Comment: You could use the second answer of [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12032/create-new-window-with-current-directory-in-tmux)

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful. `new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"` is working but what I need is to set the path permanently, i.e.: I'm working in a project in /aaa/bbb but somehow I when I change path to say /ccc/ddd and start new with C-b and c I want to land one more time in /aaa/bbb. Can you think of a solution to this?

Comment: I am personally fine with the addition of the last three lines in my `.tmux.conf`. That way I only have to navigate once to the folder and then create my windows / split from there, but I admit this is not a solution to your problem, that's why I didn't post an answer !

Comment: @lewiatan Mind editing the one-line answer `attach -c "#{pane_current_path}" ` into Lqueryvg's answer? I almost missed your comment down there and definitely your edit up here ^^'

Comment: @nuala I'm not sure what do you want me to do. Feel free to edit my post and/or the answer if you can improve it

Answer (score 126, accepted):

#### tl;dr

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>
  <kbd>:</kbd>
- `attach -c desired/directory/path`

#### Long Answer

1. Start `tmux` as follows:

   ```
    (cd /aaa/bbb; tmux)
   ```

Now, any new windows (or panes) you create will start in directory `/aaa/bbb`, regardless of the current directory of the current pane.

2. If you want to change the default directory once `tmux` is up and running,  use `attach-session` with `-c`.

Quoting from the `tmux` man page for `attach-session`:

```
    -c will set the session working directory (used for new windows)
    to working-directory.
```

For example:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>
  <kbd>:</kbd>
- `attach -c /ddd/eee`

New windows (or panes) will now start in directory `/ddd/eee`, regardless of the directory of the current pane.

Comment: Second option is exactly what I wanted. I'm going to use `attach -c "#{pane_current_path}"` which would be the same as what I have had in screen. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! `attach -c` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: `attach -c` works like a charm.

Comment: If you are working with bash scripting, cd <dir>\n tmux new-session <options> worked for me

Answer (score 7):

For those who might be looking for a bit more reference than the selected answer provides, there was an another good answer to this question over on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307815/how-to-change-the-starting-directory-of-a-tmux-session

Which provides ways you can do it without leaving the session, and for those who use tmux in a multi-session fashion (like myself), the above answer gives a bit better context as to how `attach`/`attach-session` works.

See both available answers for different ways they can be used.  I found both to be helpful/insightful.